# android How to add multiple image in ParcelFileDescriptor

Tags: android

I'm getting single and multiple images from gallery.single image is working fine.then getting multiple images via clip-data to stored array list.how to add multiple images in ParcelFileDescriptor?and how to get multiple images via bitmap?.after getting multiple images or path how to send multiple or single  images in server?

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri selectedImageUri = null;

    **ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<>();**

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            if (data.getData() != null) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();

                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            System.out.println("item------->" + item);
                            Uri selectedImage = item.getUri();
                            System.out.println("selected------->" + selectedImage);
                            **mArrayUri.add(selectedImage);**

                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } else {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                try {
                    System.out.println("Image size------>" + mArrayUri.size());

                    **parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImageUri, "r");**
                    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    view.setImageBitmap(image);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Comment: what do you need ParcelFileDescriptor for?

Comment: how to send multiple images in ParcelFileDescriptor(**parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(multipleIimage, "r");**)

Comment: what do you need ParcelFileDescriptor for?

Comment: I'm received multiple images path from clip-data and stored ArrayList(mArrayUri.add(selectedImage)). how to show multiple image in my page(Activity)?ParcelFileDescriptor means, which has to convert  the image path to imageview via bitmap.

Comment: just use `ImageView#setImageUri`